# How to store the value of a counter for a high score table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a whack-a-mole game in javascript and I need to figure out how to make a highscore table. I was thinking an HTML5 database would work nicely, but I can't figure out how to integrate it. I have a counter that counts the number of successful clicks on the moles. I need to take it's value and store it in the database and then draw it later for the highscore table. It also needs to place the scores correctly(the highest being at the top of course) Functionality for being able to store player name would be nice but not necessary. Can anyone give me an example of this? My counter code is

```
document.getElementById("randomdiv"+r).onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
```

It's displayed on the page via this code

```
<div id='counter'>0</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to implement an HTML5 database to store your counter on a local machine or how to make the counter code you showed work?  It may be easier to store the high score info in a cookie which will work in all browsers.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to implement a HTML5 database/cookie to store information to make a high score table. The counter already works in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can find many resources on the net.
Some useful resources might be:

- [HTML Database tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)
- [Answer about Browser compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784/which-browsers-support-html5-offline-storage)

The first link will give you a deep overview on how to implement/use HTML 5 database feature.